# Databricks error saying missing files on changing cluster config

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, autoload

I get the error  on below script

> "Error while reading file
> /mnt/topics/audit-logs/minio.sys.tmp/multipart/v1/c782.025a337657/azure.json.
> A file notification was received for file:
> /mnt/topics/audit-logs/minio.sys.tmp/multipart/v1/c782.025a337657/azure.json
> but it does not exist anymore. Please ensure that files are not
> deleted before they are processed. To continue your stream, you can
> set the Spark SQL configuration spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles to
> true."

```
table_name= "main.deltalake_db.Table_test"
checkpoint_path = "/mnt/_checkpoint"
file_path ="/mnt/topics/audit-logs"
schema = "authenticationMechanism STRING,authenticationMechanismId STRING"
(spark.readStream
  .format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .schema(schema)  
  .load(file_path)
  .writeStream
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .trigger(availableNow=True)
  .toTable(table_name))
```

This was working fine earlier but I changed the cluster config and also mounted the location by providing keyvault scope.. Now everything breaks.. I tried to move to original configuration but same error. Can some one help. Where should i move this config thing in the script?

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is missing the file. To avoid this error and continue the stream running below Spark SQL configuration code.

```
%sql

SET spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles = true;
```

Or add the `spark.conf.set`  before `readstream` as below.

```
table_name= "main.deltalake_db.Table_test"
checkpoint_path = "/mnt/_checkpoint"
file_path ="/mnt/topics/audit-logs"
schema = "authenticationMechanism STRING,authenticationMechanismId STRING"

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles", "true")

(spark.readStream
 .format("cloudFiles")
 .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation",
  checkpoint_path)
   .schema(schema)  
   .load(file_path)
   .writeStream
   .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
   .trigger(availableNow=True)
   .toTable(table_name))
```

And try running your code.